# How to automatically add locks around every method call of an external class?

Tags: c#

I have a dll from an external developer that is C based and has a C# wrapper around it. The individual calls are not thread safe and according to the developer I need to lock each of the calls myself.

I started adding the locks to some of them and noticed that it is a pain to implement (mind-numbing copy-paste of a code snippet) and causes my code to become super ugly and non-readable. I am now wondering if there is an easier way. Right now it looks like this:

```
lock (LockObject)
    Wrapper.DeleteAllSequences();
lock (LockObject)
    Wrapper.UploadSequence();
lock (LockObject)
    Wrapper.StartSequence();
```

There got to be some sort of construct that automatically adds a lock around each method I call from the wrapper - and not requiring me to do this manually every time.

Comment: I would say: Either change the wrapper, or build a wrapper around the wrapper...

Comment: There's no reason to do that.  You need to put a single lock around *your* code that's trying to access that method from multiple threads. You need to identify *which* methods can run in a single thread too - what if multiple threads call `DeleteAllSequences()` or `UploadSequnce()` one after another? Using multiple locks would allow that. I doubt that's what you want though.

Comment: First of all, *do* you have multiple threads? What kind of application are you building? What does the library do? If you need those 3 methods to run in a single thread, you could use `lock(xx){  Wrapper.DeleteAllSequences(); Wrapper.UploadSequence(); Wrapper.UploadSequence();}`. On the other hand, you could ensure only one thread has access to that library, by putting the relevant code in a separate class that uses its own thread. Or, if you can combine all library operations in a single call,  you could use an ActionBlock<T> which uses only 1 thread per input message by default

Comment: @JHBonarius yeah that's what I thought but don't want to do :D was hoping there is a construct that I am not aware of that would allow me to skip that work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am aware of using a larger lock statement - the calls are dispersed throughout my class though and I just used them to illustrate my question.

Comment: @DanielM What you ask for does not exist, as I know, so you must implement it like with `CallLocked`.

Comment: @DanielM bring them back under a single class that controls access to the library then. Or find a way to have only *one* thread work with that library. Eg a producer/consumer scenario, where multiple clients (what clients? Web app, desktop? Task.Run? It *matters*) send requests to a single worker. One such possible implementation would use an ActionBlock<T>.

Comment: @DanielM frankly, you have to explain your specific use case. There are a *lot* of ways to solve the problem without using `lock`. Dispersed thread-unsafe calls are a serious problem anyway, the code would have to be refactored